# Type mismatch error of Unit instead of Int (Scala)

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to define a tail recursion factorial function like this:

```
def anotherFactorial(n: Int): Int = {
    def factHelper(x: Int, accumulator: Int): Int = {
      if (x <= 1) accumulator
      else factHelper(x - 1, x * accumulator)

    factHelper(n, 1)
    }
  }
```

But it gives me a mismatch error saying that it found a Unit type instead of an Int and I cannot see how, I've checked other Scala questions with the same error (like this one: [Scala Type Mismatch Unit Instead of Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072126/scala-type-mismatch-unit-instead-of-int)) but doesn't seem I'm making those mistakes.

This is the error message:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong brackets. You have:

```
def anotherFactorial(n: Int): Int = {
  // the body with only def is Unit
  def factHelper(x: Int, accumulator: Int): Int = {
    if (x <= 1) accumulator
    else factHelper(x - 1, x * accumulator)
    factHelper(n, 1)
  }
}
```

rather than

```
def anotherFactorial(n: Int): Int = {
  // the body with only def is Unit
  def factHelper(x: Int, accumulator: Int): Int = {
    if (x <= 1) accumulator
    else factHelper(x - 1, x * accumulator)
  }
  factHelper(n, 1)
}
```

I recommend using some formatter like [scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) often (e.g. on compile) to spot issues like this immediately. Additionally if you annotated `factHelper` as `@scala.annotation.tailrec` compiler would fail as this wrong bracket makes it non-tail-recursive, so it would also help spotting the issue.